# SSIS: Unable to Read from Excel file from a UNC path when deployed to server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I appear to be unable to get my deployed SSIS package to read from a 1997-2003 Excel file.
I get stuck with the following 2 errors:

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR, Error code: 0x80004005 An OLE DB
> record is available. Source Microsoft JET Database Engine, database
> engine cannot open the file, it is already opened exclusively by
> another user, or you need permission to view its data.
>
> DTS_E_CANNOTAQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER with Error code 0xC0202009

The package itself works with no issues when using SQL data tools on the server logged in as the service account only when deployed to server I see this issue.

To make this issue even more confusing I have setup and tried the following:

- Runtime is set to 32 bit on the debugging menu on SQL data tools as well as the job configuration is set to use 32 bit runtime
- I am able to UNC to the folder/file when logged in as the SQL service account

Any Ideas?

Thanks,
M

Comment: Forgive the obvious question, but are you sure no one has the file Excel file open when the job is trying to run? I've seen this error hundreds of times, and it was always exactly what it said it was.

Comment: 100% contacted the user who has had it closed. Also activated the shared workbook feature in excel which I have tested with our development environment and works fine.

Comment: Also - Can you make sure that the SQL Agent job is running under the same A/C as the SQL Service A/C that you logged in as (& you are not using proxies)

Comment: I can confirm that is also the case. The service account is running on all SQL services.

Comment: Can you put a test (clone) excel file in the same UNC folder, be sure to close it, and see if the package can access it instead?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. Turns out I missed a step with the permissions.

Yes the Service account had permissions to the folder but I failed to add read permissions to the file itself.

Thanks for all comments/suggestions.

M